# Typescript strongly typing child object

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I want to convert angular plain vanilla JS code to Typescript. Consider this code fragment :

```
app.someController = function ($scope) {    
// var $scope.Data = null;
var $scope.Data: SomeCollection = null;
```

I'm attaching Data to scope. I want it to be of type SomeCollection. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm attaching Data to scope. I want it to be of type SomeCollection. How can I do it ?

The type annotation *needs to go on scope*. So :

```
interface MyScope extends ng.IScope{
        Data: SomeCollection
}
app.someController = function ($scope : MyScope) {  
$scope.Data = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface MyScope : ng.IScope{
        Data: SomeCollection
}
app.someController = function ($scope : MyScope) {  
}
```